# What is a labelable element?

Tags: css, html, accessibility, wai-aria

I have been [reading on accessibility](http://www.w3.org/TR/aria-in-html/#fifth-rule-of-aria-use) and a concept I cannot find accurate information on stumbled upon me: HTML labelable elements.

I understand that the concept behind a labelable element is one that can be properly wrapped or referenced by a `<label>`, for example:

```
<label>
    Enter some data
    <input type="text"/>
</label>
```

Or for example:

```
<label for="anInputField">
    Enter some data
</label>

<input type="text" id="anInputField"/>
```

Does anyone know exactly what labeable HTML elements are and which are not?

**Bonus Round!**
Can you elaborate on why the **[fifth rule](http://www.w3.org/TR/aria-in-html/#fifth-rule-of-aria-use)** of ARIA use is a work in progress? In my own websites, I would like to be able to account for future changes to that, but I don't know why it's not set in stone (seems like it should be).

Comment: The fifth round is a work in progress because the spec is the "working draft", so by definition that spec is in development.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_label

Comment: @eichertc — The tells us nothing that isn't already specified in the question itself.

Comment: @eichertc — If something is wrong with it (which there isn't) then try explaining the problem instead of linking to an example with no explanation.

Comment: I think the fifth rule is work in progress because there ought to be other ways to specify an element's accessible name - through the `aria-label` and `aria-labelledby` attributes, but I suspect browser/accessibililty tool chain support is too patchy to recommend right now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to MDN, the following elements are labelable.

Excerpt from [Content categories](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories):

> labelable
>   Elements that can be associated with  elements. Contains `<button>`, `<input>`, `<keygen>`, `<meter>`, `<output>`, `<progress>`, `<select>`, and `<textarea>`.

Comment: good answer! Do you have any insight regarding the **bonus round**? it's not obligatory of course

Comment: @QGE I'm not sure on that one. I wouldn't worry too much about what is listed changing though. It would break a lot of things.

Answer (score 3):

The link in the current [HTML 5 recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#category-label) (unlike the one to the HTML 5.1 draft in the ARIA draft you link to) isn't broken. It says:

> Some elements, not all of them form-associated, are categorized as labelable elements. These are elements that can be associated with a label element.
>
> button input (if the type attribute is not in the hidden state) keygen meter output progress select textarea

Answer (score 1):

The definition of a `labelable element` has to be understood from the definition contained inside [HTML51 Semantics](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/semantics.html#category-label)

> These are elements that can be associated with a `label` element.

**Bonus**: This rule is still a work in progress because, as you expected, this rule is still a draft (and is totally incomplete).

1. To have an [`accessible name`](http://www.w3.org/TR/accname-aam-1.1/#dfn-accessible-name) won't be enough as long as this accessible name is not a correct alternative for the given element.

For instance, the following code has an *accessible name*, inside the `title` attribute which does not convey enough information to understand the field.

```
 <input type="text" name="firstname" value="" title="name001" />
 <input type="text" name="fullname" value="" title="name002" />
```

2. You do not have to use the accessible name at the expense of accessibility

The following example has an *accessible name* which will give Assistive Technologies a correct alternative, but won't benefit to users not using those given technologies.

```
 <input type="text" name="firstname" value="" aria-label="First Name" />
```

See First rule:

> If you *can* use a native HTML element [[HTML51](http://www.w3.org/TR/aria-in-html/#bib-HTML51)] or attribute with the semantics and behaviour you require **already built in**, instead of re-purposing an element and adding an ARIA role, state or property to make it accessible, **then do so**.