# Display form fields on same line

Tags: css

I am trying to get my select form fields all on the same line. Below is my code. i have tried adding `display:inline;` to both the select and the label, but it doesn't seem to change anything.

HTML:

```
   <form id ="myform1">
   <label for='orgUnit'>Organization Unit</label>
   <select name="orgUnit" id="orgUnit">
        <option value="Select">Please Select an option</option>
        </select>
    <label for ='org'>Organization</label>
    <select name="org" id="org">
        <option value="Select">Please Select an option</option>
        </select>
    <label for ="bu">Business Unit</label>
    <select name="bu" id="bu">
        <option value="Select">Please Select an option</option>
        </select>
<label for ="department">Department</label>
<select name="department" id="department">
        <option value="Select">Please Select an option</option>
        </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="buID" id="buID" >
</form>
```

CSS:

```
select {

width: 175px;
}

label {
width:130px;
text-align:right;
padding-right:10px;
}
```

So I added the for attribute and removed the br tags but now it looks like this.

[image: currentlook]

Sorry, found the answer, I had some more CSS that caused the labels to float and look like they do in the image.

Comment: have you tried with inline-block ?

Comment: you can try twitter bootstrap  ( http://getbootstrap.com/  ) . lot lot of possibility to enhance your website style, display etc ...
loot at the "Grid system" http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Answer (score 1):

Take out the `<br>` tags. Those are causing your new lines.

```css
select {
  float:right;
  width: 175px;
}

label {
  float:left;
  width:130px;
  text-align:right;
  padding-right:10px;
}
```

```html
<form id ="myform">
   <label>Organization Unit</label>
   <select name="orguniy" id="orgUnit">
    <option value="Select">Please Select an option</option>
    </select>
<label>Organization</label>
<select name="org" id="org">
    <option value="Select">Please Select an option</option>
    </select>
<label>Business Unit</label>
<select name="bu" id="bu">
    <option value="Select">Please Select an option</option>
    </select>
<label>Department</label>
<select name="department" id="department">
    <option value="Select">Please Select an option</option>
    </select>
<input type="hidden" name="buID" id="buID" >
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

removing the `<br>` tags would help a lot.

```
 <form id ="myform">
 <label>Organization Unit</label>
 <select name="orguniy" id="orgUnit">
    <option value="Select">Please Select an option</option>
    </select>
<label>Organization</label>
<select name="org" id="org">
    <option value="Select">Please Select an option</option>
    </select>
<label>Business Unit</label>
<select name="bu" id="bu">
    <option value="Select">Please Select an option</option>
    </select>
<label>Department</label>
<select name="department" id="department">
    <option value="Select">Please Select an option</option>
    </select>
<input type="hidden" name="buID" id="buID" >
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AGE/c52xpwux/)**

HTML

```
<form id="myform">
  <label>Organization Unit
    <select name="orguniy" id="orgUnit">
      <option value="Select">Please Select an option</option>
    </select>
  </label>
  <label>Organization
    <select name="org" id="org">
      <option value="Select">Please Select an option</option>
    </select>
  </label>
  <label>Business Unit
    <select name="bu" id="bu">
      <option value="Select">Please Select an option</option>
    </select>
  </label>
  <label>Department
    <select name="department" id="department">
      <option value="Select">Please Select an option</option>
    </select>
  </label>
  <input type="hidden" name="buID" id="buID">
</form>
```

So why does this look different from what you currently have? That is due to your improper usage of the `<label>` tag. Please refer to **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34322466/what-is-a-labelable-element)** Stack Overflow question to better understand how a label element is properly used.

In short: it must use either a **[for attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label)** or it must surround the element it references, in your case the `<select>` tag.

I also took the liberty of removing your `<br/>` tags, you can add spacing using the CSS `margin-top` or `margin-bottom` property on your labels.

CSS

```
label > select {
  width: 175px;
}

label {
  display: block;
}
label:nth-child(1) > select{
  margin-left: 40px;
}
label:nth-child(2) > select{
  margin-left: 72px;
}
label:nth-child(3) > select{
  margin-left: 67px;
}
label:nth-child(4) > select{
  margin-left: 80px;
}
```

The CSS change is very simple, I added custom `margin-left` to each `<select>` tag in order to have them aligned properly.

***Why is this so different from the other answers?*** Because I interpreted your below statement:

> "I am trying to get my select form fields all on the same line"

as a way to suggest you need them vertically aligned. Otherwise, any of the other answers will easily do the job if you need them to be in a single line.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your labels and inputs in `<div>` with div as an `inline-block`.

Here is some inspiration:

[Bootstrap inline form](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline)